# Maintain Scroll-Position on PostBack

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, scroll, postback

I use Visaul Studio Community 15.5.2 with WebForm and C#

some suggest

```
<%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" .....
```

and on web.config

```
 <pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" ></pages>
```

i tried, but the maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack has no effect, even without scripts, with no browser (Edge included)

this code work with a only one DIV

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onload = function () {
    var div = document.getElementById("dvScroll");
    var div_position = document.getElementById("div_position");
    var position = parseInt('<%=!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["div_position"]) ? Request.Form["div_position"] : "0" %>');
        div.scrollTop = position;
        div.onscroll = function () {
            document.getElementById("div_position").value = div.scrollTop;
        };
};
  </script>
```

the DIV with a HiddenField, everything works perfectly.

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="dvScroll"; style="width:450px; height:300px; overflow:scroll; float:left">
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" CellPadding="4">
          <Columns>         
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID_NAVE" HeaderText="IdNave" ItemStyle-Width="50" ItemStyle-wrap="false" Visible="true" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="NOMENAVE" HeaderText="nave" ItemStyle-Width="15" ItemStyle-wrap="false" Visible="true" />
          </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="div_position" name="div_position" />
```

But with a second DIV the code is not applicable (window.onload=function() is unique, it would be nice to modify the script to accept the DIV as a parameter, but I don't know JS

```
<div id="dvScroll2"; style="clear:both; width:600px; height:300px; overflow:scroll;">       
       <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField2" runat="server" />
       <asp:GridView ID="GridMnuRest" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="4" OnRowCreated="GridMnuRest_RowCreated" OnRowDataBound="GridMnuRest_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridMnuRest_SelectedIndexChanged" OnSelectedIndexChanging="GridMnuRest_SelectedIndexChanging" OnRowCommand="GridMnuRest_RowCommand">                            
           <Columns>       
            <asp:TemplateField >
              <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="MnuSelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="GridMnuRest_OnCheckedChanged" />
              </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>                  
           <asp:BoundField DataField="id_ristorante" HeaderText="IdRst" ItemStyle-Width="20" ItemStyle-wrap="false" Visible="true" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="Description" ItemStyle-Width="300" ItemStyle-wrap="false" Visible="true" />
          </Columns>
       </asp:GridView>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" id="div_position2" name="div_position2" />
```

even if I create a new script with changed variables

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onload = function () {
    var div2 = document.getElementById("dvScroll2");
    var div_position2 = document.getElementById("div_position2");
    var position2 = parseInt('<%=!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["div_position2"]) ? Request.Form["div_position2"] : "0" %>');
        div2.scrollTop = position2;
        div2.onscroll = function () {
            document.getElementById("div_position2").value = div2.scrollTop;
        };
};
```

Comment: `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"` normaly works. Why not in your case can't be seen from the question, there not enough code to reproduce it. Please have a look on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In your project check if you have file `Scripts\WebForms\WebForms.js`, where the functions for saving and restoring of scroll position reside.

Comment: I added WebForms. js file on "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Web Tools\Packages\Microsoft. AspNet. ScriptManager. WebForms. 5. 0.0\content\Scripts\WebForms", tested, even on Edge, but the result does not change, without Java scripts always returns to the first line of the GridView.
Had it been so simple, there would not be much discussion on this subject.
thank you, however, for your contribution.

Comment: OK, so _in your project_ you have the script file like this : `scripts\webforms\webforms.js` with Build Action set to `Content`. And somewhere e.g. in your master page you have the script reference added to the `<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">` e.g. like this : `<asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />` right? And it still doesn't work?

Comment: Try to create the minimal verif. example where this problem can be reproduced.

Comment: works correctly but can only be used in one DIV (only accept one instance asp: ScriptReference Name...)
on section Head <script runat="server"><form id="form1" rnat="server">
 <div id="dvScroll"><asp: ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"><Scripts><asp: ScriptReference Name="WebForms. js" Assembly="Web system" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms. js" /></Scripts></asp: ScriptManager>

Comment: ** Problem Solved **
1) on Head  <script runat="server"></script>
2) after <form id="form1" runat="server"> add a DIV
3) inside DIV add <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server"> add script  <Scripts> <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" /> </Scripts> </asp:ScriptManager>
4) add a DIV , and add a UpdatePanel and a DIV for GridView
<div id="dvScroll"; ..."> <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server"> <ContentTemplate> </asp:GridView> </ContentTemplate> </asp:UpdatePanel.